# Getting compile error in template class C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on one project with jsons with use of Jsoncpp library. I created template class with following method:

myValue is type T;

```
template <typename T>     
void SerializableScalar<T>::deserialize(const Json::Value& token)
{
    if (isDeserilizationPossible(token)) {
        if (token.isInt())
        {
            myValue = token.asInt();
        }
        if (token.isString())
        {
            myValue = token.asString().c_str();
        }
        if (token.isDouble())
        {
            myValue = token.asDouble();
        }
        if (token.isBool())
        {
            myValue = token.asBool();
        }
    }
}
```

And I get folowing errors:

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'double'   
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'int'
```

I am quite getting why I get these errors, I am mixing more types in one method. I came with one solution to overload this method and set specialization for this class. But is there any cleaner solution? I am looking for something simple.

Comment: What type is `myValue`? Seems like it's a `const char*`. If it is, then it has nothing to do with templates; instead, it's a type mismatch, after all, you're trying to save arbitrary types into a `const char*` without appropriate conversion (even with conversion, I don't think that this approach will lead to your desired result).

Comment: All the if-statements will have to compile, even those that are not taken.

Comment: yes i understand thats why i getting these errors, but i am looking for nice clean solution without overload this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to detail what `myValue`, I assume it is of type `T`.

All the code flows (the branches of the if-else blocks) need to be valid code and compile. This is true even if a branch may never be executed. `T myValue` would need to be valid for all the return types in the function.

What you are probably looking for it to dispatch the assignments to their own functions using a "tag dispatch" technique. A classic compile time technique would not work here, it would need to a run time evaluated construct. One technique could include the conversion member(s) (`as...` et al) of the `token` object.

Comment: y, exactly.  That sound it could help. i will look at this technique . thaks.

Comment: and yes, myValue is T

Answer (score 0):

One simple idea (not the best I think): specialize for each possible T value:

```
template <typename T>

void SerializableScalar<T>::deserialize(const Json::Value& token)
{
    std::cerr << "Error: no generic deserialization" << std::endl;
}

void SerializableScalar<int>::deserialize(const Json::Value& token)
{
     if (isDeserilizationPossible(token))
     {
         if (token.isInt())
         {
            myValue = token.asInt();
         }
         else 
         {
             std::cerr << "Error: cannot deserialize to int" << std::endl;
         }                 
    }
}
void SerializableScalar<char *>::deserialize(const Json::Value& token)
{
     if (isDeserilizationPossible(token))
     {
         if (token.isString())
         {
             myValue = token.asString().c_str();
         }
         else 
         {
             std::cerr << "Error: cannot deserialize to string" << std::endl;
         }                 
    }
}
void SerializableScalar<double>::deserialize(const Json::Value& token)
{
     if (isDeserilizationPossible(token))
     {
         if (token.isDouble())
         {
            myValue = token.asDouble();
         }
         else 
         {
             std::cerr << "Error: cannot deserialize to double" << std::endl;
         }                 
    }
}
void SerializableScalar<bool>::deserialize(const Json::Value& token)
{
     if (isDeserilizationPossible(token))
     {
         if (token.isBool())
         {
            myValue = token.asBool();
         }
         else 
         {
             std::cerr << "Error: cannot deserialize to bool" << std::endl;
         }                 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible for OP; looks like they're trying to do the type checking at runtime rather than compiler time.